# How do I specify the name of unite() in a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

How can I make this code work?

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
             b = 6:10)

name <- c('foo', 'bar')

df %>% unite(name[1], 1:2, sep = ';')
```

I get this error code: `Error: Must supply a symbol or a string as argument`

What I want basically is this:

```
df %>% unite(foo, 1:2, sep = ';')
```

Output:

```
   foo
1  1;6
2  2;7
3  3;8
4  4;9
5 5;10
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df %>% unite(!!name[1], 1:2, sep = ';')`?

Comment: If you remove the subset it seems to give you the desired result: `df %>% unite(name, 1:2, sep = ';')`

Comment: @jpsmith while it does work, I don't have the option access bar this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it with:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5,
             b = 6:10)
name <- c('foo', 'bar')

df %>% unite(!!name[[1]], 1:2, sep = ';')
```

Using `!!` tells tidy verse the status of evaluation for the `var` in question

"In order to tell [unite()], that the variable `name[1]` has already been quoted we need to use the !!-Operator; pronounced Bang-Bang"
[!! Info](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/07/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/)